# Web push notifications not showing since Chrome switched to OSX notifications

Tags: service-worker, web-push

Since Chrome switched to the native OSX notifications, sometimes the notifications I try to show using web-push and my service worker do not appear.

They appear consistently in previous versions of Chrome.

Is there anything I'm supposed to have changed since they moved to make this work?

Comment: Chrome has not switched yet as far as I can tell. Should the question be edited to reflect that?

Answer (score 18):

1. Make sure "DO NOT DISTURB" is toggled off:
   Notification Center > Notifications (Scroll to the top)

[image]

2. Open Notification Center > Notifications > gear button  in the lower-right corner of Notification Center
   (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204079)

On the Notification Settings:
Click on Google Chrome (Badges, Sounds, Banners):
[image]

And toggle on "Allow Notification from Google Chrome":
[image]

Answer (score 9):

There are a few reasons why notifications may not show, but it's likely that your site has the existing notifications still open in the notification center (click the very top right icon of your screen to verify they are there), and that you're updating these with a static tag rather than showing new notifications.

If clearing the notifications from the notification center causes this issue to go away then the issue is that you need to add `renotify: true` to the options you pass in to showNotification, or clear the previous notifications programmatically and show a new one either with the same tag or a new tag.

Comment: you're such a lifesaver. As it turns out "Do not disturb" was activated in the notification tab. After turning that off, everything is back to normal!

Comment: For anyone seeing this. It took me a day to figure out why me web push notifications were not working in Safari, Chrome or Firefox. It was the Do Not Disturb function in the notification tab of my System Preferences indeed. Which was 'turned on' when 'mirroring to TVs and displays'. I had an external screen connected to my macbook......

Comment: Yes foe me chrome was off on mac, that was my issue, it worked on safari

Comment: Thanks guys. I was in "Do not disturb" mode too. Just lost one hour of my life.