# Web push notification not showing

Tags: javascript, web, push-notification, service-worker, web-notifications

I registered a service worker and am trying to test a web notification in the browser. Chrome (and Firefox) claim the service worker is successfully registered.

[image]

On load of the React App, I've granted permission to receive notifications.

[image]

In my `sw.js`, I am listening for a `push` event, and attempting to send a sample push message from the Chrome Application tab, as shown in the screenshot above.

```js
self.addEventListener("push", receivePushNotification);
```

When clicking `Push` in the Chrome Application Tab, the `push` event fires, calling `receivePushNotification`. However, when I attempt to show a notification in the browser, nothing happens and no error is reported.

```js
function receivePushNotification(event) {
  // This prints "Test push message from DevTools."
  console.log("[Service Worker] Push Received.", event.data.text());

  var options = {
    body: "This notification was generated from a push!"
  };

/*****
  I would expect the following line to display a notification, since I've already 
  granted permission to allow for notifications. Yet, nothing happens and there is 
  no error in the console.
*****/

  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification("Hello world!", options));
}
```

Comment: Does this happen in production only or locally as well? 
I do suggest you create 2 vapid sets, one locally for testing and another for production. Make sure you handle calling the right vapid keys based on your environment.
I have a gist on github that has what you need. https://gist.github.com/waelio/6f2a792e60c0e5ea9441af0cbb4f554c

Comment: Check if the OS' do-not-disturb mode is on, as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61651174/3112241

Comment: Well.. for me devtools push button only worked with https.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have gone one step too far in defining your function separately / not defining it as an async function. You are also not passing the event to the function call.

What happens if you rewrite it like this?

```
self.addEventListener("push", function(event) {
  console.log("[Service Worker] Push Received.", event.data.text());
  var options = {
    body: "This notification was generated from a push!"
  };
  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification("Hello world!", options));
});
```

Comment: The `event` is implicitly passed to the function reference. Notice I left a comment on the first line of my function that states how I do, indeed, receive the text being pushed from the Chrome Devtools.

Comment: If you want to keep the service worker alive then the event.waitUntil method must be initially called within the event callback and has to be passed a promise. The browser will then keep the worker alive until the promse settles. So if you want to use a named function it needs to be async and return a value upon resolve/reject. What happens if you try my example code above?

Comment: Downvote reason: there's no difference between your example code and the code in the question. Specifically: the event handler function in your example code is not async either.

Answer (score -1):

This is the code that I use. It is pretty generic, and it works.

```js
self.addEventListener('push', function (e) { 
  console.log('Push Received...')
  const data = e.data.json()
  self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
    body: 'Notified by Waelio.com!',
    icon: 'https://picmymenu.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/waelio_logo.png',
  })
})
```

Comment: I added in the comments a link to a gist that handles the subscribe and unsubscribe functions.
 https://gist.github.com/waelio/6f2a792e60c0e5ea9441af0cbb4f554c